# Is it possible to create a view of contacts that's based on global tags from the accounts to which they belong?

Tags: account, contact, tag, massemailmessage

I need to notify people at a set of accounts that a product they've purchased has been updated.

This is not the long term solution that I want, but what I did for the time being was put global tags on each account representing ownership of the product license.

My question is, can a view of contacts be set up that allows me to create a mass email to all of the contacts at accounts tagged with a certain global tag?

Comment: It looks like, in addition to other obstacles, you can't refer to a tag in a formula custom field either.  Am I right about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One custom solution i can think is have a custom field on account and populate with specific code related to all products and then you can trigger emails through trigger to those contacts .

Comment: This is more or less the easiest way to do it.  What I did was to create a custom field on the account that is a pick list.  Then I defined all of the possible values and populated each account according to what they purchased.

When I created a mass mailing, I was allowed to choose this account field as a filter for the view that selected the contacts to which the email was sent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking at coding effort given that this is not a long term solution.
But if you are then an Apex job may help. Use "accounttag" table to get a list of all accounts with given tag using which you can get all contacts associated to those accounts and send emails.
Finally, you can run the job with a combination of "on update workflow" on Product object and email services.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but we don't want to go in that direction because of the effort involved.